# best place to store backup encryption key

Tags: encryption, server, backup

I have a server on which I keep an encrypted backup of some data. The server updates the backup once a day if the data has been changed and is physically accessible to many people. Further, I would like to have easy access to these backups. Given these considerations, where would be the best place to store the encryption key?

Comment: What software are you using ? What encryption scheme ? Symmetrical or asymmetrical ?

Comment: The data that needs to be stored is a database from a web application. The application is hosted on Windows Azure servers and I don't have the possibility to encrypt it there. the backup server is on an office therefore I can't have much control on the physical access. The solution I came up so far was to sent the key from a symmetric encryption through email to a group of 'trusted' people. But I like the idea of an asymmetric encryption... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the *encryption* key and also the *decryption* key. If you are using [asymmetric encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) then the two keys can be distinct (though mathematically linked to each other), to the point that the encryption key can be made *public*.

In your situation, I assume that your server somehow obtains the clear data from an external source, and *stores* only an encrypted version of the data. If your server is hijacked (and malicious people with physical access can certainly hijack your server) the attacker just waits for the next batch of data and slurp it before it gets encrypted.

Solution is to change your model:

- Have *the source* encrypt the data, not your storage server.
- Use asymmetric encryption, so that the source needs only know the public key, not the private key.
- Don't decrypt on the storage server either; decrypt on your laptop, onto which you download the encrypted backup files when needed. The private key is in your laptop.
- Now that the storage server is not trusted for anything (it never sees the decryption key, nor the clear text data), replace the server with some cloud-based service, it is cheaper.

Storing secrets, *any* kind of secret, on a machine which potential attackers can physically access, is an absolute no-go. This will never be safe. There can be some [mitigation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module), but that's very expensive, and not as complete as you would wish (it is more about post-mortem audit than proactive defence).

Comment: The data that needs to be stored is a database from a web application. The application is hosted on Windows Azure servers and I don't have the possibility to encrypt it there. the backup server is on an office therefore I can't have much control on the physical access. The solution I came up so far was to sent the key from a symmetric encryption through email to a group of 'trusted' people. But I like the idea of an asymmetric encryption...    Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If someone has physical access to your server, it's not your server anymore. If you are too afraid to store the encryption key on your disk (which can be retrieved from your disk if stored on there). Another option is to run those backups manually and every time insert the password yourself manually. But if someone manages to dump your memory or just installs a key-logger on your machine (considering they have physical access) your key will not be secure, even when introduced manually.

In short: make sure no-one can access your server physically.